# How to consume GraphQL api using spring boot Resttemplate

Tags: python, java, spring-boot, graphql, resttemplate

I want to consume a graphQL endpoint in a springboot application using resttemplate

Whenever,I am make a POST request with the query and variables I am always receiving the same error {"errors":[{"message":"Bad request"}]}

Below is the sample query, I want to send,

```
{
  "query": " query ($filter: SearchFilter!, $limit: Int!, $sorting: SearchSorting!) { search (filter: $filter, limit: $limit, sorting: $sorting)
  { cursor totalCount documents { id title products { name primaryCode } count Date type { ids } } } }",
  "variables": {
    "filter": {
      "date": {
        "dt": "2023-01-01"
      },
      "types": {
        "ids": [
          "1"
        ]
      },
      "products": {
        "include": [
          "aaa"
        ],
        "available": True
      },
      "category": {
        "ids": [
          "A12"
        ]
      }
    },
    "sorting": {
      "by": "DATE"
    },
    "limit": 500
  }
}
```

But from Python, I don't have any issues on consuming the endpoint, and I am geting response.

Python code:

```
params = {
            "filter": {
      "date": {
        "dt": "2023-01-01"
      },
      "types": {
        "ids": [
          "1"
        ]
      },
      "products": {
        "include": [
          "aaa"
        ],
        "primaryOnly": True
      },
      "category": {
        "ids": [
          "A12"
        ]
      }
    },
    "sorting": {
      "field": "DATE",
      "direction": "DESC"
    },
    "limit": 500
}

query = '''
        query ($filter: SearchFilter!, $limit: Int!, $sorting: SearchSorting!) { search (filter: $filter, limit: $limit, sorting: $sorting)
  { cursor totalCount documents { id title products { name primaryCode } count releasedDt type { ids } } } }'''

result = json.loads(requests.post(uri, headers=getHeaders(), json={'query': query, "variables": params}).text)
```

Help to know how I can send query and variables using spring **resttemplate**.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I can tell you on this... There are good libraries out there that can simplify this process for you.

Since you are using spring I would start off by grabbing the dependecy listed here:
https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot
Source docs: https://www.graphql-java-kickstart.com/spring-boot/getting-started/

Using this dependency offers ease of consumption as you can set the query to be in a more readable format by placing your queries in the resources folder like

query.graphql

From there

You can create a model object containing all of the values you are expecting to be returned by your graphql response. I would just make a pojo class using:  https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Then to consume here is an example:

```
   // If no other function is calling then remove the docID param. Could be used to enable specific searching
public Example graphQl(String docID){
    
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("TheEndpointURI")
            .defaultHeader("apikey", "apikey value")
            .build();
    
    Map<String,Object> vars = new HashMap<>();
    vars.put("docId", docID); // remove if not using docID
    vars.put("filter", "anyFilters you might want?" );
    
    GraphQLWebClient graphQLWebClient = GraphQLWebClient.newInstance(webClient, objectMapper);
    
    Example example = null;
    
    try{
        
        example = graphQLWebClient.post("query.graphql", vars, Example.class).cblock();
        
    } catch (Exception e){
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    return example;
}
```

Example query.graphql

```
    query bookDetails {
  bookById(id: "book-1"){
    id
    name
    pageCount
    author {
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
}
```